# Explicitly defined route not working, error states "couldn't find foo with id=do_foo"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a controller method called `do_foo`.

```
  def do_foo
    Foo.do_foo
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
    end
  end
```

In `routes.rb` I have:

```
resources :foos
```

...then I defined:

```
get "foos/do_foo" => "foos#do_foo", as: :do_foo
```

When I rake routes, I have:

```
do_foo GET    /foos/do_foo(.:format)                foos#do_foo
```

If I try to click a link with `do_foo_path`, or if I try to hit the url `localhost:3000/foos/do_foo, I get:

```
Couldn't find Foo with id=do_foo
```

Should I be creating this route in the `foo's` resources block?  How would I do that?

Comment: I just realized I can move the custom route above the resources route in `routes.rb`.  Is that the appropriate solution?

Comment: yes, it is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the "why" it fails:

`routes` is order-dependent. You define the `resources` route *before* the `get` route, so it's trying to use `do_foo` as an ID. If you moved it *before* the `resources` route, it would work.

As you guessed, though, it'd probably be better to add as a resourceful collection route.